# GSON/Jackson - how to parse array of arrays of variable types

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a JSON looks like:

```
{"response":[[215,{TypeA},{TypeA},...,{TypeA}],[{TypeB},{TypeB},...,{TypeB}]]};
```

215 is some integer number, changes in each response, it's not important.
TypeA, TypeB is some classes of my application.
How i can parse JSON to get TypeA/B[] or List?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution for Jackson here http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html